# infinite looping using scroll overflow-x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Target to achieve**

I manage to make a result using **overflow-y infinite looping**,

i'm trying to make something different

What i'm trying to do is when the user scrolling overflow-x and the width document will increase +++ .

But the result that i get right now is the height of document are increase.

JS

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($(window).scrollLeft() >= $(document).width() - $(window).width() - 10) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            var box = $("#scrollbox");
            var aj = $(".set");   
            box.html(box.html() + aj.html());

          }, 100);
      }
 });
```

Please help me.

Your help really appreciate

Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/sydnj8q6/2/)

Comment: Should be scrollLeft not scrollTop, when you go for overlow-x

Comment: @axel.michel i already update my code. That was previous code. The result what i want does not achieve that i want. The document of height aj.html still increase.

Comment: Also, you must increase the width of your container `.test` to accommodate the new `p` elements. Otherwise they will stack vertically.

Comment: @JLF can you show me how to do that? i'm still beginner in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your style to be like this:

```
p{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 80px;
}

.test{
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/u00fqtec/